# What are the pros and cons of using an email as a username?

Tags: email, authentication

You know most login forms use user & pass.

And some go the email & pass. What are the pros and cons of them? Here is what I have thought of.

**PROS of email**

- one less thing to remember (as opposed to remembering a username too)
- Should always be unique per user
- One less thing you need to ask them to register

**CONS**

- If they change email - could the potentially try and use their new email to access the site?
- For forget password - and it says 'please enter your email' and they have abandoned their old email - they could potentially be stuck.

I do believe this is programming related because ease of use of a web application is something important that shouldn't be overlooked.

Comment: For the forgotten password con, it does not matter if the email address is the user id if they have abandoned the old email address.

Comment: I share your point of view. An email was the natural username: unique by design. I don't know what went wrong. In any case, the next user id is the OpenID.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the pros and cons of using an email address as a user id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647172/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-using-an-email-address-as-a-user-id)

Comment: for adding a possible issue: if by some means, the old account is flawed and must be removed, if you use email-as-username system, you will have hard time for "creating the new user with the same email" vs. "keeping track of the old user in system"

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Another thing to remember is that if other users can also see the "username", you shouldn't use mail addresses due to privacy issues.

Comment: Not always. The username should never be the public facing name. That goes for email as username or just usernames. Seperate the username (or email) from the public "presence" name.

Comment: You can use email and password for authentication and a "display name" for representation

Answer (score 5):

OpenID and OAuth .....It just appears better. Even less users to manage for them and it makes migrating in one place easier on a change.

Yes, you have to be careful. I would insist that the backup email address (an additional profile field) is different than the email address they are using for the user. Many systems also have some other fields that then can use to authenticate themselves if things get really hairy. At this point though, it would frequently require a tech support call.

Depending on the type of system, using email may be a security vulnerability. I know your email address, I don't know what you might put into a username prompt. If being able to easily guess a username is an issue, then I would not use email address.

Comment: And to make things even easier, may I suggest using a 3rd party service like Auth0.com since they have all the plumbing to the different OAuth providers already figured out .. and they support other authentication methods, such as Active Directory.  Your app can work with a JWT which is portable, secure and does not have to reveal the user's info.

Answer (score 5):

Another problem that may arise when using the email as username is "user harvesting" attack.
For example, if you have a "change email" page or when creating new user, if the new user insert an email which is already exist then the application will have to send back an error. Consequently, an attacker can discover all the users in the application by executing a simple script (in case the user doesn't exist it will be added )

Comment: This can be solved like this: The site should not tell whether the email exists or not. It should simply send a mail to the newly entered email with an appropriate text, with a formulation that depends on whether the mail existed or not. The immediate response from the site should inform that a mail has been sent of course, and tell the user to check his mailbox.

Comment: This might be mitigated by something like fail2ban .. but then again the user could get around that by harvesting over a distributed network .. but then again that gets tricky.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the cons outweigh the pros where security is concerned. Many companies recycle email addresses, hence, if a user no longer uses an email address (deleted his/her email account), it MIGHT be recycled back for any other person to use.

In that case any other person may receive periodic correspondence from your organization. This lets the new user know that the previous user of the account used to have a login with your organization. If you use simple email based password resets, without extra checks such as security questions, then all they need to do is recover the password using the email address they now own and they have access to that person's account.

I hope you are not programming for a bank. USBank.com uses a username and not a email. I also have an account with a credit union and they don't use email either but instead use account numbers, which they never recycle.

If security is the priority, never use email.

Comment: I think that usually there's a `Forgot your password?` link that sends your username and a reset-password-link. So even if you login by username (and not email), you'd be in danger if email addresses are recycled. (You wouldn't consider yourself safe just because no periodic correspondence was sent that revealed the login identifier?)

Comment: @KajMagnus :: Yes, but at least you will still be able to get into your account to update the email address to your own email address. If the application sends an email to the original email address to ask for confirmation that the email address should be changed [which I have seen before] then you'll be screwed. Moreover, it will only [usually] send a reset password link *if* you can authenticate another security check - something along the lines of a customer number (like Go Daddy does) or a PIN, or your phone number etc. Allowing a password reset without a secondary check is noobish.

Answer (score 3):

Email makes a good username as long as you provide a means for changing the email address.  LinkedIn provides this as you create an account with an email as the username.  They also allow you (once logged in) to change the primary email address which then changes your username to be that email address.

As long as you do something like this then you should be all set.

Comment: In the event that something happens and the email address cannot be recovered for lost passwords, I would recommend having some form of email or phone communication for account recovery. In my oppinion, you should have this anyway, regardless of if you use usernames or email as usernames. Use account demographics to confirm the user is who they say they are.

Answer (score 1):

Email (pro) - lessens account-creation spamming because you could confirm their account by sending an email to them.

Comment: You can require an email address to link to the account and verify the account by that email address. This does not change if you have a username for authentication. I recommend it though.

Comment: Practically every site you sign up for will ask for an email address, regardless of whether it's used as the username or not.

Comment: It takes just seconds to create a spam email account and have it set up with a auto responder. If you have ever managed any type of online forum before where users are required to respond to an email to activate their account you will find out quickly that it doesn't slow down spammers at all.

Answer (score 1):

Con: 
When you require a username to be shared among applications such as web site and email, it can raise security concerns. For example, whoever has access to the usernames in the web site will also have access to the email addresses if the email is use for the username. Usually this is not a problem, but it could be. It is generally a good policy to keep usernames and passwords separate between applications unless there is a common login procedure, or unless security is not important.

Comment: Generally if they have access to the username that will probably have access to the email address as well because access to the username usually requires some database accessibility. If they have access to the database they have access to more then just the username. At least thats my oppinion.

Answer (score 1):

CON: It's one less insulating layer between the user and spammers.  If, somehow, somebody got a full list of usernames, they would be able to spam all your users.  But if the site uses usernames, with emails as a secondary field, this isn't a concern.

Unless they get all user data, of course, but that's a much bigger problem anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I've done this for b2b apps and its a real pain when a user leaves a client company an someone else is using the old deactivated email address as a login and purposely not changing it to avoid getting email from us.

We end up with password-reset email that bounces and support calls to fix things.

Answer (score 1):

Another note if you're going to allow accounts to be public is that not requiring a username means you have to allow for a "Display Name" (you certainly wouldn't show an email address), but if your users want to use their real names there's potential for duplicate names which could cause confusion (think two SO commenters with no pictures and the same name, the assumption is that it's the same person unless you clicked through to a full profile). In that case you'd either have to force a unique Display Name (which could keep someone from using a real name) or just accept that you may have two Bob Johnson's hanging around confusing people.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Email addresses, it's easier for a member to change their username, for example when pwng0d69 wants to be known as Jon Skeet.
However for each site that asks for my email address, personally I cringe at yet another source of potential spam.

Use Open ID :)

Answer (score 0):

PRO: It seems that some services are considering making e-mail the standard for identifying a specific user across the net:

e.g. http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/08/14/google-points-at-webfinger-your-gmail-address-could-soon-be-your-id/

CON:
This hasn't happened yet, and there are lots of other options such as OpenAuth and OpenID that are around now and have some support (you also have login using Facebook spreading).

Just tailor your choice for identity to whatever the target audience of your app will be.

Answer (score 0):

We used Arena Solutions 'Product Lifecycle Management' software before a change in company ownership mandated a change. It was one of those deals where all your sensitive company data is hosted somewhere offshore and could be accessed by browser from anywhere.

Arena PLM was touted as highly secure, but the (default) behaviour was to require an email address as a username. It allowed strong passwords with an expiry date, but when my password expired I was told I could choose another one, or just continue to use the old one!

I think the security claims were based on the use of SSH for data transfers, but it seemed to me a determined person could log in because

- The usernames were publically available **company** email addresses, and
- There was plenty of time to guess a password because a lazy user wouldn't choose a new one.

It means, of course, that the use *and renewal* of strong passwords **must be enforced**.